# Converting from 240v to 117v

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage, voltage-regulator

I want to convert this device from 240v to american 110v
I noticed on the bottom of the photo i have a blue wire going to 240v input.
Can i simply move the blue to 117 to make it work in US?
or do I have to change the transformer as well? (41305H0000 / TB-60)

[image]

Comment: It appears that the Gray plug that contains the Blue wire, may be plugged in reverse. In Europe the Blue wire is Neutral, Brown is Hot, Green/yellow is Ground. In the USA, White is Neutral. DO NOT fuse the Neutral or Ground lines, and you may need to add a polarized plug to the US cord to eliminate any possible connection errors. Verify which line the Fuse is in, and move the Hot line to the 117 location. (The Blue wire may not be from the power cord, the photo does not give that information, so the Blue wire may just be used internally in the device.)

Answer (score 1):

Eh, you might.  Can you take the board out and post a picture of the back?  Generally those sort of line voltage selection jumpers change the transformer tap configration.  However, it looks like that they may have cheaped out on this one as there are unconnected pins on the header going to the transformer.  Looks like there should be a yellow and an orange wire there that are not present.  Not surprising as it's made in china - a transformer with no taps will be a little bit cheaper than one with taps.

Alternately, if you can't take the board out, can you unplug the transformer and line voltage selector and use a multimeter to figure out which line voltage select pins are connected to the transformer header?  If the 117 volt pin is connected to one of the unconnected pins going to the transformer (which I suspect) then you're going to have to swap out the transformer, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried swapping the blue to 117 input but nothign happens. probably is correct what you said. I can buy another transformer, they are cheap... the output voltage seems to be  around 9v (still AC.. is it possible?)

Comment: i don't know much about electronics...if i buy a transformer 117 > 12v is that ok or do i burn anything?

Comment: You can probably get away with that.  However, I would like to see a picture of the back of the board first to make sure that nothing else is connected on the AC side.

Comment: I'll try to remove it...it's just a pain in the butt to unscrew everything ;) Doe the code on the transformer mean anything? I'm trying to find some on Jameco but with no results...